# How to disable a button until http request is loaded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, httprequest

I am trying to implement a flutter app to fetch data from an API end point. I've already implemented the fetch function on button press.

Although, I want the button to get disabled (to avoid multiple clicks) while the request is being fetched!

I implemented it using the dart **http** package.

Here's my code for the same:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(Home());

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String _advice = '';
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App 1'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Text 1 - advice
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '$_advice',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Text 2 - counter
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Floating button
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.file_download),
          onPressed: _fetchPost,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _fetchPost() async {
    final url = 'https://api.adviceslip.com/advice';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    dynamic body = json.decode(response.body);

    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _advice = body['slip']['advice'];
        _counter += 1;
      });
    }
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    else {
      // throw Exception('Failed to load post');
      print('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the bloc pattern, if so you can just wrap the button in a Stream Builder. This StreamBuilder listens on the 'BehaviorSubject<bool> buttonEnabled'. When starting the request you do 'buttonEnabled.sink.add(false);'. And when the request is finished you do 'buttonEnabled.sink.add(true);' 

In the Button you then just use snapshot.data for the argument enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a property like isLoading and set it before and after performing the request

also you can disable FloatingActionButton by setting onPressed to null. ([Learn More](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html))

here is your code with this approach

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(Home());

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String _advice = '';
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App 1'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Text 1 - advice
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '$_advice',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Text 2 - counter
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Floating button
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.file_download),
          // You can disable the FAB by setting this property to null
          onPressed: isLoading ? null : _fetchPost,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isLoading;
  setLoading(bool state) => setState(() => isLoading = state));

  _fetchPost() asnyc {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await _fetchData();
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  _fetchData() async {
    final url = 'https://api.adviceslip.com/advice';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    dynamic body = json.decode(response.body);

    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _advice = body['slip']['advice'];
        _counter += 1;
      });
    }
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    else {
      // throw Exception('Failed to load post');
      print('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a custom button to address this functionality.

```
class FutureHandlerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const FutureHandlerButton(
      {Key? key, required this.futureFucntion, this.label})
      : super(key: key);
  final Future<dynamic> futureFucntion;
  final String? label;

  @override
  State<FutureHandlerButton> createState() => _FutureHandlerButtonState();
}

class _FutureHandlerButtonState extends State<FutureHandlerButton> {
  bool isAllowPress = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: isAllowPress
          ? () async {
              setState(() {
                isAllowPress = false;
              });
              await Future.wait([widget.futureFucntion]);
              setState(() {
                isAllowPress = true;
              });
            }
          : null,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          if (isAllowPress)
            const Icon(Icons.access_time)
          else
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                strokeWidth: 2,
              ),
            ),
          const SizedBox(width: 5),
          Text(widget.label ?? 'Press Me'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```